# How do I open 2 chromium windows from terminal?

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi4

I would like to open 2 chromium instances from terminal but this does not work. I'm currently using raspberry

```
chromium-browser --window-position=0,0 chromium-browser --window-position=1920,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute the following in the terminal:

```
   sudo chromium-browser --no-sandbox & sudo chromium-browser --no-sandbox &
```

--no-sandbox is necessary on the Raspberry Pi.